# Chrome book downloads

Tags: chromebook

How do I protect chrome book downloads. I had a close call w/ forgetting my old password and erasing all local data. I’ve since signed on successfully and want to preserve downloads and local data

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure true data preservation is to not keep it all in one place.
There's an adage:

> Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered **temporary**.

This isn't only for such times as you might forget a password - what would happen if the device was dropped & failed completely; or if it was lost or stolen?
So, you need backups.

The simplest, but least safe or secure, is to keep data on a USB key/SD card. You cannot rely on this as the only backup, as they are prone to total failure at the most inopportune moments… and never, ever use one as the only location for any data.

Your second backup should be on an HD; at least once a day. Kept on premises.

Your third needs to be off-premises; either at the home of a relative or online. This is for if the house burns down - in case of total catastrophic failure.